# How to remove a cloned draggable which has been dropped into a container?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I created a widget builder app where you can drag widgets (draggables) onto a widget builder (droppable). Multiple widgets (clones) can be dragged onto the builder, the clones are draggable, and the clones are constrained within the builder.

I have provided a small box in the upper right corner of the widget builder where I would like to use it as a trash can (of sorts; to remove the clone if dragged onto it).

Can someone help me with creating the ability to remove a clone if the clone is dragged onto the trash area?

Here is my example: http://jsfiddle.net/mitchslap/K8VKa/

Thank you thank you thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Set 'greedy' param to 'true' in drop function in your droppable container:

```
$("#trashWidget").droppable({
    greedy: 'true',
    accept: function() { return true; },
    drop: function () { tolerance: 'fit', alert("Dropped!"); }
});
```

I've just tested this function and it seems to work flawlessly :)

Good luck!

Comment: Wow thank you. That seems to be working. Im a jquery noob and this is all very new to me. QUESTION: I replaced the alert with the remove function and it removes the parent. I tried several iterations of this and cannot figure out how to remove the object we dragged into the trash widget. Any ideas?  Thanks. Here is revised code: $("#trashWidget").droppable({
                greedy: 'true',
                accept: function() { return true; },
                drop: function () { tolerance: 'fit', $(this).parent().children().remove(); }
            });  http://jsfiddle.net/K8VKa/28/

Comment: try: drop: function (event, ui) { tolerance: 'fit', $(ui.draggable).remove(); } . Updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/K8VKa/30. ui param has all info about draggable element :) hope it helps!